# Multiple selected file in webview shows no file chosen

Tags: java, android, webview

I want to upload multiple images in webview and i can select many file but when i chose file and tap open Webpage Input show no file.

```
     @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
    Uri[] results = null;
    //Check if response is positive
    if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == FCR){
            if(null == mUMA){
                return;
            }
            if(intent == null){
                //Capture Photo if no image available
                if(mCM != null){
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                }
            }else{
                String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                if(dataString != null){
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }
    }
    mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
    mUMA = null;
}else{
    if(requestCode == FCR){
        if(null == mUM) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUM = null;
    }
}
```

}

and my onShowFileChooser code is

```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
```

i searched on internet but can't find any suitable answer.